# 3-sat to 2-sat reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, np

It is known that [3-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-satisfiability#3-satisfiability) belong to - [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) complexity problems, while [2-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) belong to [P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29) as there is known polynomial solution to it.

So you can state that there is no such reduction from **3-SAT** to **2-SAT** unless $P=NP$.

I am looking for strong proof for this state, regardless NP belong to P or not.

Answer (score 11):

You can prove it by contradiction:

Suppose that $P \neq NP$ and there is a polynomial-time reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT; then 2-SAT is NP-complete, but 2-SAT is also solvable in polynomial time, so
for all decision problems $A \in NP$ you can decide $x \in A$ reducing $x$ to the corresponding 2-SAT instance in polynomial time and solve it in polynomial time (and the total time is still polynomial); so $A \in P$ and hence $NP \subseteq P$. But we also have $P \subseteq NP$, so $P = NP$ which is a contradiction. :-)

Comment: If $P \neq NP$, there could not be a polynomial-time reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT, you cannot make assumption for both $P \neq NP$ and there is a polynomial reduction from 3-sat to 2-sat.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand well your question ... what is exactly the "state" you would like to prove?

Comment: @Babibu: he is showing what you asked for. "There is no reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT unless P = NP" is equivalent to "If there is a reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT, then P = NP", which is equivalent to "If P $\ne$ NP, then there is no reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT".

Comment: @Vor I wan't to prove that dependently if NP belongs to P or not, there is no reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT. This is what I call a strong proof.

Comment: @Babibu: if you prove it then you would solve the P vs NP question :-)

Comment: @Vor [I know](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20103/proof-verification-p-neq-np) lol. I thought it is obvious.

Comment: @Babibu: You might want to specify what sort of reduction you want. Do you want not only a many-to-one reduction, but a reduction which preserves the number of satisfying assignments? Or perhaps one which preserves *the set* of satisfying assignments?

Comment: @Babibu (It is also worth noting that yes, it is obvious that a many-to-one reduction from 3-SAT to 2-SAT exists if and only if P=NP. The problem is that it is not nearly as easy as you seem to think, to prove that there is no such many-to-one reduction.)

Comment: Vor, I think the OP's problem is much more basic and about mathematical proofs. He doesn't understand the indirect proof you are giving. That is why he is asking for what he calls a "strong" proof.

Answer (score 1):

one could provably use 2SAT to solve 3SAT problems, ie a *reduction*, its just that there is not a *P-time/space* reduction unless P=NP. in other words, converting 3SAT to 2SAT, or reducing 3SAT instance $A$ to 2SAT instance $B$, is indeed possible *(using extra 2SAT variables and clauses!)*, but all known techniques lead to an "exponential blowup" in the size of $B$ wrt $A$ (ie *space* which also implies *time*). this shows how important it is to measure *time/space* requirements of a reduction and in fact there are many different ways to measure the complexity of a reduction. P-Time reductions are just more basic/common but many more complex "reduction complexities" are studied. so in this case in fact a *P-time* reduction from 3SAT to 2SAT exists *iff* P=NP...

Comment: ps the 3SAT/2SAT dichotomy is indeed an interesting way to try to understand the P=?NP question, and also relates to an important phenomenon in the field known as the _transition point_ where instances move from P-time solveable to non-P-time solvable.

Comment: There's certainly a P-space reduction: solve the 3SAT instance in the reduction and map to true or false, as appropriate.

Comment: fine, "nontrivial PSpace reduction"

Comment: some clarification. note added after feedback from Sameer Gupta... the idea is a nontrivial ExpSpace reduction. the idea is also to use extra/ auxilliary/ "ancilla" bits on the 2SAT formula. ie not 1-1 relationship between variables in the $A/B$ formulas. the 2SAT instance $B$ is true iff the 3SAT instance $A$ is, but only over a limited set of variables in $B$ mapping to corresponding variables in $A$. (there might also be a way to do it without extra variables...?)

Comment: Why does anyone care about a nontrivial EXPSPACE reduction for a problem that can trivially be done in polynomial space?

Comment: why does anyone care about abstract cstheory? or undecidable problems that cant be solved? etc? as the original question wonders and answers indicate, the not-exactly-simple dichotomy between P-Time 2SAT and NP-Complete 3SAT is tied up with one of the central mysteries of CS, P=?NP. it also relates to deeper aspects such as the SAT "easy-hard-easy" transition point. admittedly it can be regarded as a pedagogical or artificial construction. in a way _all_ problems can be converted to each other with complexity "pushed into" reduction functions (as you state). this is a basic point rarely noted.

Comment: Let me try again. You are telling us about a new reduction from 3SAT to 2SAT. We already know that such a reduction exists: in fact, it's obvious that one exists and that infinitely many exist. So, for your new reduction to be interesting, it must be somehow "better" than the existing reduction. Your new reduction is considerably less efficient than the known one, since it requires exponential, rather than polynomial space. It is also much more complicated. It produces a larger output. What properties does it have that compensate for all of this?

Comment: let me try again. feel you are missing the main point of the answer. _generalizing,_ a theory of how to create 2SAT formula(s) that "mimic" a 3SAT formula via reduction theory (an interpretation to me getting at the main point of the original question) is different from the trivial construction above of solving 3SAT and mapping to true or false, although thats a trivial case of a general theory. more sketch/ ideas in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18801528#18801528). (some analogy, consider the [Tseitin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation).)

Comment: update, SG has turned this into a [cstheory question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/properties-expressible-in-2-cnf-or-2-sat) (thx for that). my intuition could be off, have to think about this more based on those comments that say not all Boolean functions are expressible in 2SAT, never noticed that before. by the way, see the confusion. am looking at 2SAT/3SAT in terms of characterizing sets of bitvector solutions in this answer, not as decision problems per se.